# Mesh shows in wireframe mode after removing smoke stimulation

Tags: 3d-view, interface, smoke-simulation, wireframe

I made a solid mesh and then added a smoke stimulation on it.

The stimulation worked but i didn't want it so I deleted the bake and removed the stimulation but now the mesh appears as wireframe even in rendered view in viewport

But the video and image renders show it as a colored solid mesh

How can I make the mesh shown as solid mesh in viewport

Comment: You can adjust the viewport display of the objects in the Object Properties Panel: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/display.html

Comment: Thanks it woked

Answer (score 0):

Select your object, then go to *Object Properties > Viewport Display*. Set the *Display as* option to *Solid*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).